# How to assign to any_type of utree

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, c++03

I've written a parser for arithmetic expressions as part of a larger project (~25 rules and counting) and I'm trying to add the capability of parsing a function call inside such expressions.

In short, what I'm trying to do is assign a `FunctionCall` to the `utree` via its `any_ptr` member.  Here's a short form of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>

struct FunctionCall
{
    //...
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit;
    qi::rule<
        std::string::iterator, FunctionCall()> function;

    qi::rule<
        std::string::iterator,
        utree()> expression;
    expression = function[_val = &_1];
}
```

This compiles, but as you can see the semantic action is in all likelihood going to take the address of a temporary variable and pass that to the `utree` (I haven't even bothered to run it, that's how sure I am).

So my questions are:
What is the correct way to assign a `FunctionCall` object to the `utree`?
Does it have to be through the `any_ptr` member?
In which case I assume it requires a dynamically-allocated copy of the object to be assigned to it, so how do I specify that in a semantic action?
Lastly, I seem to have a hard time finding documentation for `any_ptr`, is it a smart pointer as well or do I have to manually delete what I put into it?

Comment: I love Boost Spirit, but this is getting a bit too masochistic for me. If it's undocumented, I'd stay away. In general, utree isn't slated to stay: [comment of the dev on the topic](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Utree-tutorial-tp4652706p4652736.html)

Comment: @sehe, well that settles that I guess.